# How to add a Linear Progress Indicator once the submit survey button is clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, indicator, flutter-packages

I want a linear progress indicator and a circular progress indicator to appear after the user clicks submit survey.

Also, is there a better way to write a survey code without using the survey kits package?

Below is the complete code for the assignment that was used:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:survey_kit/survey_kit.dart';


void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: Scaffold(
    body: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: FutureBuilder<Task>(
          future: getSampleTask(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.hasData &&
                snapshot.data != null) {
              final task = snapshot.data!;
              return SurveyKit(
                onResult: (SurveyResult result) {
                  print(result.finishReason);
                },
                task: task,
                themeData: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
                    primarySwatch: Colors.cyan,
                  ).copyWith(
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  primaryColor: Colors.cyan,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                      color: Colors.cyan,
                    ),
                    textTheme: TextTheme(
                      button: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.cyan,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  iconTheme: const IconThemeData(
                    color: Colors.cyan,
                  ),
                  outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Size(150.0, 60.0),
                      ),
                      side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (Set<MaterialState> state) {
                          if (state.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            );
                          }
                          return BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.cyan,
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                      shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (Set<MaterialState> state) {
                          if (state.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .button
                                ?.copyWith(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                );
                          }
                          return Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .button
                              ?.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.cyan,
                              );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.button?.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.cyan,
                            ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  );
 }

 Future<Task> getSampleTask() {
 var task = NavigableTask(
  id: TaskIdentifier(),
  steps: [
    InstructionStep(
      title: 'Dear Customer,\nCongratulations!',
      text:
           'Simply take this short survey about your experience with us.\n\nClick LET\'S GO!         to   begin.',
      buttonText: 'Let\'s go!',
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 1 out of 7:',
      text: 'Which type of shipping do you use most often?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Letter', value: 'Letter'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Parcel', value: 'Parcel'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Oversize shipping', value: 'Oversize shipping'),
          TextChoice(text: 'None of the above', value: 'None of the above'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 2 out of 7:',
      text:
          'Do you agree for the Pricing for the type of shipment you prefer?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'),
          TextChoice(text: 'No', value: 'No'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Not sure', value: 'Not sure'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 3 out of 7:',
      text: 'How would you rate our package tracking system?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Excellent', value: 'Excellent'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Good', value: 'Good'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Not good', value: 'Not good'),
          TextChoice(text: 'Not sure', value: 'Not sure'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 4 out of 7:',
      text: 'Have you ever used our complaints department?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'),
          TextChoice(text: 'No', value: 'No'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 5 out of 7:',
      text: 'Would you consider recommending our shipping/courier service?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'),
          TextChoice(text: 'No', value: 'No'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 6 out of 7:',
      text: 'Have you ever participated in our survey rewards program?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'),
          TextChoice(text: 'No', value: 'No'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    QuestionStep(
      title: 'Question 7 out of 7:',
      text:
          'Would you like to receive notifications about sales and discounts?',
      answerFormat: SingleChoiceAnswerFormat(
        textChoices: [
          TextChoice(text: 'Yes', value: 'Yes'),
          TextChoice(text: 'No', value: 'No'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
   //This is where the Submit Survey button is
    CompletionStep(
      stepIdentifier: StepIdentifier(id: '321'),
      title: 'Done',
      text:
          'thanks for taking the survey!',
      buttonText: 'Submit survey',
    //I want it to take the user to a new page where aminated percent indicators are used
    ),
  ],
);
task.addNavigationRule(
  forTriggerStepIdentifier: task.steps[7].stepIdentifier,
  navigationRule: ConditionalNavigationRule(
    resultToStepIdentifierMapper: (input) {
      switch (input) {
        case "Yes":
          return task.steps[0].stepIdentifier;
        case "No":
          return task.steps[7].stepIdentifier;
        default:
          return null;
      }
    },
  ),
);
return Future.value(task);
}

Future<Task> getJsonTask() async {
final taskJson = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/example_json.json');
final taskMap = json.decode(taskJson);

return Task.fromJson(taskMap);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linear progress indicator has been added to the newer versions of the survey_kit. By default the circular progress indicator appears after you submit your survey.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).